# Make queryset with multiple date range

Tags: django

I have some date field in a model and what I need it is to aggregate the number of rows in the model by a date range.
I have, on example - date1, date2, date3, date4, date5
I can get the row numbers for any range:

```
number1 = Model.objects.filter(date__range=(date1, date2)).aggregate(Count('id'))
number2 = Model.objects.filter(date__range=(date2, date3)).aggregate(Count('id'))
....
```

Then I need to join that sub-numbers in one queryset.
I know that I can use: number1 | number2 | ... or itertooks.chain,
but what I need it is queryset but not list or something else.

What would you suggest me?

Additional info:
Thanks for yours replies. 
But it seems I was no clear enough. 
What I need it to get something like this: 2 fields, data-range and number.
Seems it is not possible to get records number within date interval using Q object.
I managed to get it with this plain SQl:

```
sql1 = "Select COUNT(*) as count from table where date_created BETWEEN date1 and date2".
```

After I used QuerySet extra:

```
qs=qs.extra(select={'number1': sql1, 'number2':sql2 ...}).
```

So I have got the queryset with number1, number2,.. fields and related values.
But what I wanted it is to get 2 field:

```
data_range, number
range1, number1
range1, number1
```

and have many rows with data. 
I think I can get it with sql request using UNION:
    sql1 UNION sql2 UNION sql3 ..
Seems it is not possible with Django ORM, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: "what I need it is queryset but not list or something else" - why?

Comment: I need return queryset from the 'queryset' method of some admin.ModelAdmin class.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and [this way of using annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Comment: try with something like ```Q(start_date__gte == date1) &(Q(end_date__lte ==date2))```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

A quick and dirty example would be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

number1 = Model.objects.filter(Q(date__range=(date1, date2) | Q(date__range=(date3, date4))
```

This would return a queryset where the dates are either between `date1` and `date2` *or* between `date3` and `date4`.

I also *think* that you want `annotate` and not `aggregate`. `annotate` is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). I'm a little unclear on that part from your question, though.

Either way, fundamentally, the solution you want is `Q` objects.

Comment: Be mindful that when you use ORs with `Q` objects, you'll likely end up with duplicates in your queryset. Use `.distinct()` to remove them.

Comment: Thanks for yours replies. But it seems I was no clear enough.